# i don't want to make logout after reloading page angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, logging, angular-cli

It's logged out after refresh page , how can i keep the user logging in after reloading ?

This is header.component.html:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown-menu-left" ngbDropdown dir="rtl">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link" ngbDropdownToggle> John Smith </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
        <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="onLoggedout()">logout</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

this is logout function :

```
onLoggedout() {
    this.authService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/login'])
}
```

This is authService:

```
logout(){
    firebase.auth().signOut();
    this.token = null;
}
```

This is auth-guard.ts:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private authService:AuthService) { }
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated();
}
```

Comment: whats your requirement ? you need to logout user without refreshing page ? or something else ?

Comment: when i refresh the page it's logged out , i need to make the page refreshed without logging out .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand your problem, you need to follow these steps:

- Firstyl when you login you need to store your `token` in the localstorage.
  (i am assuming `token` keyword as flag that user is login)
- once you logout clear your localstorage using

  localStorage.clear();
- Than as your case once you press `back button` of browser user will not allowed to access page before login, for this you need to make changes in your authGuard file as follow

  ```
   constructor(private router: Router, private authService:AuthService) { }
   canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
     if(localStorage.get('token'))
         return true;
     else
         return false;
    }
  ```

if still need any help let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know,it's you expect answer.But you can try to save token to localStorage.

Comment: it works but when i press back button after logging out, it backs to home page without logging in again .

Comment: You have to remove token localStorage,when logout.

Comment: I understand now what are you said.I did some researh.Everyone use cookies for this problem.If I find alternative solution,I will write.

Comment: Yes,I tried something else in my project. I checked does localStorage have token in ngOnInıt function.If null,client will redirect login page with this code:" return this.router.navigate(['/loginpage']); ". But I'm not sure it's good solution.

Comment: @ÖmerSÖNMEZ please see my answer , for better way i guess

Answer (score 0):

Save your session in cookies and check each time if the cookie of the session exist. This library may help you to manage cookies easily [Angular2-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cookie).